# Proof regarding the fundamental theorem of abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group of prime - power order and let$a$ be an element of maximal order in $G$ , then $G$ can be written in the form $< a > \times \:\: K$ , where $ K = \{x \in G | x^{n} = e \}$.

This is represented as a lemma in the book I'm reading ( Joesph A. Gallian)..

We prove this by induction on $n$.  { $|G| = p^{n}$ }

I got the part when $n=1$.

Now for $n=k$ , we have $|G| = p^{k}$. where $k < n$ , we claim that $<a> \cap <b> = \{e\}$.

Now among all the elements of $G$ we choose an element $a$ of maximal order $p^{m}$, then , $x^{p^m} = e$ for all elements of $G$ , we assume that $ G \neq <a>$ .

Now we choose an element of $G$ of smallest order such that $b$ doesn't belong to $<a>$.

From here , what we do is , we find an element $c$ of order $p$ such that $c$ doesn't belong to $<a>$. I got the proof upto this .

Now the next statement is, " Since $b$ was chosen to have smallest order such that $b$ is not in $<a>$ thus , $b$ also has order $p$ , thus it follows $<a> \cap <b> = \{e\}$    "

Can anyone explain me this ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part.

It seems that the first "thus $b$ also has order $p$" is clearly too fast (even if we know that it is true) it could happen, a priori, that all elements of order $p$ are in $\langle a\rangle$ without having $\langle a \rangle=G$ (this is what happens for the quaternionic group with $a$ being one of the canonical generator for instance, there is only one element of order $2$).

For the second part. Once $b\notin \langle a\rangle$ of order $p$ is given.

If $\langle b\rangle\cap \langle a\rangle$ is not trivial then it contains a non-trivial element $x=b^k$ with $0<k<p$ it follows that $\langle x\rangle $ is a group of order $p$ contained in $\langle b\rangle$ so $\langle b\rangle=\langle x\rangle$ hence $b\in \langle a\rangle$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I 'm sorry but I didn't get the first one. All elements of order $p$ are in $<a>$ so how can we say $ |b | = p$. Sorry for being so obtuse.

Comment: @User9523, you are not being obtuse, actually what I say in "for the first part" (confuselly I admit) is that there is a problem in the proof you gave us. As it (maybe there is some part missing or a previous lemma doing the thing in your book...), the author seems to say that if $b$ is not in $\langle a\rangle$ of minimal order then necessarily $b$ is of order $p$. This is true in our abelian group but far from being obvious and I gave a counter-example in the non-commutative case.

Comment: We also took $ |b^{p}| = \frac{|b|}{p}$ ,So , either , $|b| = 1 $ or some higher power of $p$ , Is the fact above concluded from this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the proof does find an element c of order p such that c doesn't belong to , b also has order p because |b| divides |G| by Lagrange Theorem.